# Foreground service content intent not resuming the app but relaunching it

Tags: android, android-activity, foreground-service

I've been browsing many topics about resuming an activity from a foreground service without finding any concrete answer to my problem.

I'm trying to put a foreground service in my app, and I want the app to be resumed when clicking on the service notification instead of relaunching it. I've tried using the `getLaunchIntentForPackage()` method from `PackageManager`, which is the closest to what I want to do.

However, the activity's `onCreate` is still being called when resuming the app by clicking on the notification.

So here is my question, how to resume an app from a notification's content intent?

I'm starting my ForegroundService in the activity's `onStop` so it gets called when the app is killed or sent to background.

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    Log.v(TAG, "onStop")
    ForegroundService.startService(this, "Hellooooooo, here is the background")
}
```

ForegroundService

```
class ForegroundService: Service() {

    companion object {
        private const val CHANNEL_ID = "ForegroundServiceChannel"

        fun startService(context: Context, message: String) {
            val startIntent = Intent(context, ForegroundService::class.java)
            startIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", message)
            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, startIntent)
        }
        fun stopService(context: Context) {
            val stopIntent = Intent(context, ForegroundService::class.java)
            context.stopService(stopIntent)
        }
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val input = intent!!.getStringExtra("inputExtra")

        val launchIntent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(APP_PACKAGE)
        val contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(applicationContext, 0,
            launchIntent, 0)

        val notification: Notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_call_to_action)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .build()

        startForeground(1, notification)
        createNotificationChannel()

        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Foreground Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            val manager = getSystemService(
                NotificationManager::class.java
            )
            manager?.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding something about the `Activity` lifecycle. Whenever an `Activity` is offscreen, the OS can destroy it at will. In fact, you should expect that it routinely gets destroyed shortly after `onStop()`. Don't  attempt to "work around" this lifecycle; work with it. I think that maybe what's more important to you is that your _app_ is not being destroyed, now that you have the foreground service. Try moving your `Activity.onCreate()` logic -- the stuff you don't want executed twice -- into the app/service `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try set in the manifest for activity android:launchMode="singleInstance".
2. Do not forget set some your action to your activity intent:
   activityIntent.setAction(ACTION_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION);
3. Override onNewIntent in the activity.
4. in onCreate and in onNewIntent do check
   if(ACTION_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction()))
   { do what you need }